# PCI-Passthrough KVM/QEMU

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, virt-manager

I want to leave discrete GPU(GTX 950) for host PC and integrated GPU(HD 530 Skylake) for guest PC. Is that possible to passthrough integrated GPU? ...or I must passthrough discrete one?

Hardware:

Intel Core i5-6500
Nvidia GeForce GTX 950
Kingston 2x4GB DDR4 RAM
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
H110 Chipset Mobo.

Comment: which virtualisation backend are you using ?

Comment: Also, can you please provide the make and model of your Motherboard.  It and the graphics ship MUST support IOMMU.

Comment: GA-H110M-S2H GSM. Intel VT_x and VT_d are enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Virtualisation backend? What is that? :D

Comment: No ideas? I really need help. :)